# Pandas: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' when selecting on date column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a column with TimeStamps. I can select date ranges from this column. But after I make change to other columns in the DataFrame, I can no longer and I get the error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'".

The code below reproduce the problem:

- Generate a DataFrame with some random numbers
- Add a column with dates
- Select on the date column

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((200,3)))
  df['date'] = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=200, freq='D')
  mask = (df['date'] > '2000-6-1') & (df['date'] <= '2000-6-10')
  print(df.loc[mask])
  ```

All good:

```
            0         1         2       date
153  0.280575  0.810817  0.534509 2000-06-02
154  0.490319  0.873906  0.465698 2000-06-03
155  0.070790  0.898340  0.390777 2000-06-04
156  0.896007  0.824134  0.134484 2000-06-05
157  0.539633  0.814883  0.976257 2000-06-06
158  0.772454  0.420732  0.499719 2000-06-07
159  0.498020  0.495946  0.546043 2000-06-08
160  0.562385  0.460190  0.480170 2000-06-09
161  0.924412  0.611929  0.459360 2000-06-10
```

*However*, now I set column 0 to 0 if it exceeds 0.7 and repeat:

```
df[df[0] > 0.7] = 0
mask = (df['date'] > '2000-6-1') & (df['date'] <= '2000-6-10')
```

This gives the error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Why does this happen and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can compare a timestamp (`Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')`) to a string, pandas will convert the string to `Timestamp` for you. But once you set the value to `0`, you cannot compare an `int` to a `str`.

Another way to go around this is to change order of your operations.

```
filters = df[0] > 0.7
mask = (df['date'] > '2000-6-1') & (df['date'] <= '2000-6-10')

df[filters] = 0
print(df.loc[mask & filters])
```

Also, you mentioned you want *to set column 0 to 0 if it exceeds 0.7*, so `df[df[0]>0.7] = 0` does not do exactly what you want: it sets the entire rows to `0`. Instead:

```
df.loc[df[0] > 0.7, 0] = 0
```

Then you should not have any problem with the original mask.

Answer (score 5):

If check output problem is `datetimes` are set by `0`, because no columns for set are specified, so pandas set all columns:

```
df[df[0] > 0.7] = 0

print (df.head(10))
          0         1         2                 date
0  0.420593  0.519151  0.149883  2000-01-01 00:00:00
1  0.014364  0.503533  0.601206  2000-01-02 00:00:00
2  0.099144  0.090100  0.799383  2000-01-03 00:00:00
3  0.411158  0.144419  0.964909  2000-01-04 00:00:00
4  0.151470  0.424896  0.376281  2000-01-05 00:00:00
5  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000                    0
6  0.292871  0.868168  0.353377  2000-01-07 00:00:00
7  0.536018  0.737273  0.356857  2000-01-08 00:00:00
8  0.364068  0.314311  0.475165  2000-01-09 00:00:00
9  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000                    0
```

Solution is set only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df.loc[df[0] > 0.7, df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns] = 0
#or specify columns by list
#df.loc[df[0] > 0.7, [0,1]] = 0

print (df.head(10))
          0         1         2       date
0  0.416697  0.459268  0.146755 2000-01-01
1  0.645391  0.742737  0.023878 2000-01-02
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 2000-01-03
3  0.456387  0.996946  0.450155 2000-01-04
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 2000-01-05
5  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 2000-01-06
6  0.265673  0.951874  0.175133 2000-01-07
7  0.434855  0.762386  0.653668 2000-01-08
8  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 2000-01-09
9  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 2000-01-10
```

Another solution is create `DatetimeIndex` if all another columns are numeric:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df.loc[df[0] > 0.7] = 0

print (df.head(10))
                   0         1         2
date                                    
2000-01-01  0.316875  0.584754  0.925727
2000-01-02  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2000-01-03  0.326266  0.746555  0.825070
2000-01-04  0.492115  0.508553  0.971966
2000-01-05  0.160850  0.403678  0.107497
2000-01-06  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2000-01-07  0.047433  0.103412  0.789594
2000-01-08  0.527788  0.415356  0.926681
2000-01-09  0.468794  0.458531  0.435696
2000-01-10  0.261224  0.599815  0.435548
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it was the issue of loop.

Make sure when you grab particular filtered dataframe change your data-time columns into date-time columns by

```
df_new['date-like_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df_new['date-like-column'])
```