# Select some rows from a dataframe with date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame as the one in the image and I want to select the rows that are in a certain period of time, for example from the begining of 2005 to July 2007.

I have tried what is said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates) as

```
#Enero 2005-Julio 2007
AntCris=df.loc['2005-01-02 00:00:00':'2007-07-01 00:00:00']
```

or

```
AntCris=df.loc['2005-01-02':'2007-07-01 00:00:00']
```

even

```
AntCris=Datos.loc[Timestamp('2005-01-02 00:00:00'):Timestamp('2007-07-01 00:00:00')]
```

But I got the error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'`.

This error is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275425/pandas-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-int-and-str-when-s), but I can not solve my issue. I have also tried reindexing my df with

```
A=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.set_index(A)
```

But I got `TypeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object is not callable`.

I hope someone can bring some light over this issue as I have no idea what I am messing up.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are mixed values - datetimes with strings, if need create `DatetimeIndex` use:

```
df.index= pd.to_datetime(df.index)

AntCris=df.loc['2005-01-02':'2007-07-01']
```