# How to group timestamp and count items according to days interval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The data  is like:(Note that the dates are not consecutive)

```
                name created    label         
0   leahbirdjohnso2 2020-02-20  PATRIOTSAWAKENED    
1   leahbirdjohnso2 2020-02-21  TRUMP2020           
2   carol2busy      2020-02-23  TRUMP2020   
3   carol2busy      2020-02-24  TRUMP2020   
4   GODRUS          2020-02-25  FOXNEWS
```

if I set interval =2 days,then I got a dataframe:

```
created     counts  label
2020-02-20  1   PATRIOTSAWAKENED
            1   TRUMP2020
2020-02-23  1   TRUMP2020       
2020-02-24  1   FOXNEWS
            1   TRUMP2020
```

if I set interval = 3 days,then I got a dataframe:

```
    created     counts  label
    2020-02-20  1   PATRIOTSAWAKENED
                1   TRUMP2020
    2020-02-23  2   TRUMP2020
                1   FOXNEWS
```

Basically, I want to sum up label numbers according to label names based on time intervals. I can set any intervals by days, 3days, 7days, 15days,etc. I cheked `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275425/pandas-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-int-and-str-when-s`; but not working for me. I can use Counter to do it in a more complex way. How to do it in an elegant pandas style?

Comment: What columns are used for grouping?

Comment: `created`@jezrael

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df.created  = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="created", freq="3D"), 'label']).count()
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesnot work if the dates are not consecutive. @Nk03

Comment: your methods performs good if no dates are missing in the created, However, if some date is missing, this method will automatically add missing dates @Nk03